# Solving $\int_7^9 \frac{2}{9 + 16x^2}\,dx$ without using trigonometric substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to evaluate $\int_7^9 \frac{2}{9 + 16x^2}\,dx$ without using trigonometric substitution?

I know how to do it with trigonometric substitution, but the problem I'm doing requires me to do it with algebra only.

Comment: Partial Fraction Decomposition over $\mathbb{C}$? _Hyperbolic_ trig substitution?

Comment: By algebra only, I really mean no advanced integration techniques. I'm trying to help a friend of mine who just started integral calculus. They've only covered the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and have yet to cover u-substitution. Their book presents the antiderivative to it like it is intuitively obvious, which is why I raise the question of how to do it.

Comment: Does your friend get to know that the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is $\arctan(x)+C$? Because then it's just a matter of $u$-substitution to get the simpler form.

Comment: alex.jordan, she knows that antiderivative, but her class has not covered u-subtitution. I was worried that I missed some obvious solution that did not employ u-substitution.

Comment: Also this is a scaled Student's $t$-distribution with one degree of freedom, so if you have access to statistical tools (like software or tables) that is a roundabout way to look at this integral.

Comment: If it really came on the heels of the FToC, it's actually not terrible to ask someone to find an antiderivative for this if they know about $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ and $\arctan$, and allow themselves freedom to adjust coefficients. You don't officially "need" $u$-substitution.

Comment: One can also use Taylor series for $\frac{1}{1 - u}$, integrate term-by-term, and recognize the Taylor series for $\arctan v$, but probably most people learn $u$-substitution before Taylor series.

Comment: Some of the information about the problem-doer's background in the comments here, together with the methods used in some of the answers, probably imply a useful lesson about including more about the context of the question in the original question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$\int_7^9 \frac{2}{9+16x^2}dx=\frac{2}{9}\int_7^9 \frac{1}{1+(\frac{4}{3}x)^2}dx$$

And now let $\ \frac{4}{3}x=t$

Answer (score 3):

The antiderivative involves an inverse trigonometric function, so whether a particular method counts as trigonometric is perhaps arguable:

Here's one option:

**Partial fractions over $\mathbb{C}$**

We can factor the denominator of the integrand over $\mathbb{C}$ as
$$9 + 16 x^2 = (3 i + 4 x)(-3 i + 4 x),$$
so we can decompose the integrand via partial fractions into a an expression
$$\frac{A}{3 i + 4 x} + \frac{B}{-3 i + 4 x}.$$
One can then integrate each term separately, then recombine the terms and apply identities to recover the antiderivative. (The involved identities, of course, probably require some trigonometry to prove.)

Comment: I am writing an answer doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$\frac2{9+16x^2}=\frac29\cdot\frac1{1+\left(\frac{4x}3\right)^2}\;,$$

and let $u=\frac43 x$. You should recognize the resulting integrand as a familiar derivative. (I wrote this before seeing your comment about the unavailability of $u$-substitution. I'm not sure that you can avoid it completely, at least without using less elementary techniques. Since this one is just a scalar multiple of $x$, perhaps it can be explained without *too* much difficulty.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option:

**Hyperbolic trigonometric substitution**

This is perhaps cheating (especially from the complex point of view), but one can substitute
$$4 x = 3 \sinh t, \qquad dx = \frac{3}{4} \cosh t.$$ This transforms the (indefinite) integral to
$$\frac{1}{6} \int \text{sech } t \,dt,$$
and this integral appears on any good integral table.

Answer (score 0):

Trigonometric substitution does not work(logically), unless there is a finite product of derivatives (I call this a virtual substitution, others call it u-substitution, but it is not a real substitution). The substitution theorem in integral calculus only works if the function that is being substituted is invertible and differentiable. Trig functions have infinitely many inverse functions in an arbitrary interval, which then violates the theorem. Unless you know that the derivative of arctan(u) is $\frac{u'}{1+u^2}$, which then gives the relation for the anti-derivative -- I cannot think of any elementary and purely algebraic manipulations in which you can prove this integral.

Comment: next thing None'll be telling us that the moon really isn't made of green cheese.

Comment: Well, I am not sure as to what part of my response you are making satire of -- but, I suspect it concerns the substitution theorem of integral calculus. Many people use trigonometric substitution, which is ridiculous. Even if it was a proper method, it is much longer than other proper methods. Open any modern calculus text, and you will most likely see the methods of trigonometric substitutions being distributed.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the technical aspects of the substitution theorem, but I suspect that when performing an inverse trigonometric substitution that we are implicitly breaking the substitution into a bunch of cases, each of which involves an invertible piece. Presumably, evaluating each of these "piecewise" integrals would yield the same expression. I think that explicitly breaking up the substitution into a family of 1-to-1 cases would be a bit much for an introductory course.

Comment: Well, the inverse function of say sin(x) is defined as (-1)^n *arcsin(x) + n*π where n is any arbitrary integer. This means there are infinitely many inverse functions of sin(x), how can you differentiate an infinite amount of functions ? Trig substitution works say if you have a "friendly" bound, however trig substitution is the most difficult way to do it. Why turn a rational function or an algebraic function into a transcendental function? This adds difficulty.